# SQL Server : proper join of data with return of preferred value if present

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on multiple data tables, trying to figure out the best method of joining them. I'm using a primary table (let's name it `Devices`) along with additional ones, `Settings`. All mentioned tables contain `DeviceID`'s, which I use as a device identifier.

Thing is, that when there are distinct device records in the `Devices` table, the `Settings` table may contain more than one record per device.

The basic device table structure looks like this:

```
| deviceId | deviceName     |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 0001     | device01       |
| 0002     | device02       |
| 0003     | device03       |
```

`Settings` however uses its own records identifier, thus looks like this is many cases:

```
| recordId | deviceId | settingState   |
| -------- | -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 0001     | OK             |
| 2        | 0001     | OK             |
| 3        | 0001     | NOK            |
| 4        | 0002     | NOK            |
| 5        | 0002     | N/A            |
| 6        | 0003     | N/A            |
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this: if a device has a record present with an "OK" setting state (among all other records matching 'deviceId'), this status is to be returned. If a machine has no "OK" matching record present - then "NOK" is considered a next priority, with "N/A" returned only, when there are no "OK" and "NOK" status records returned.

Example result:

```
| deviceId | deviceState    |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 0001     | OK             |
| 0002     | NOK            |
| 0003     | N/A            |
```

So far I succeeded without an issue with JOIN on devices, when there is a 1-1 relation, however I'm stuck  on processing more than one records per device.

I tried with `CASE` but I was unable to properly construct a `JOIN` to work on `DeviceId` through separate `SELECT` statements. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by deviceid
                                order by case settingState when 'OK' then 1 when 'NOK' then 2 when 'N/A' then 3 else 4 end
                               ) as seqnum
      from settings s
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

A fun method uses aggregation:

```
select deviceid,
       coalesce(max(case when settingState = 'OK' then settingState end),
                max(case when settingState = 'NOK' then settingState end),
                max(case when settingState = 'N/A' then settingState end),
                max(settingState)
               ) as settingState
from settings s
group by deviceid;
```